# what's wrong with my php code with recursive method?

Tags: php

Here is my php code, the test method not giving wanted output, and the other weird thing is  var_dump('a') print 3 times;

my wanted output is array('qtggccc','qtff23sdf');

```
public function main()
{
    $serverIds = array('ff23sdf','ggccc');
   $res =  $this->test($serverIds);
    var_dump($res);
}

public function  test($serverIds,$imgArray = array())
{
    if(count($serverIds) > 0){
        $media_id = array_pop($serverIds);
        $imgUrl= $this->hh($media_id);
        array_push($imgArray,$imgUrl);
        var_dump($serverIds);
        var_dump($imgArray);
        $this->test($serverIds,$imgArray);
    }
    var_dump('a');
    return $imgArray;
}

public function hh($m)
{
    return 'qt'.$m;
}
```

Comment: why you passing $imgArray to test?

Comment: why do you need a recursive function? what are you trying to do? You can just take each element and prepend that string.

Comment: `test()` function is getting called 3 times, this is why you get three "a". The problem here is the logic.

Comment: Have you tried `foreach`? Sometimes it can make difficult problems seem easy!

Comment: These code is simple demo , I don't think foreach can get what I want, because the real scenario is I need to download some images from other platform,   what  if the internet is crowded, the result isn't returned,however the foreach is still running.

Comment: when I uploaded some images to third party platform using forEach of javascript , the forEach is running complete, however the result is undefined,

Comment: thanks @AntonisTsimourtos you help me  understand the  recursive method!

Comment: @kuzicala I don't see how recursion solves the problem of waiting for an image to download. Your program still has to wait, whether it is running recursively or iteratively.

Comment: @BenHillier  yes, you are right. foreach is the perfect choose. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyClass{

   private $imgArray = array();

   public function main(){

     $serverIds = array('ff23sdf','ggccc');
     $res =  $this->test($serverIds);
     print_r($this->imgArray);
   }

  public function  test($serverIds){

   if(count($serverIds) > 0){
       $media_id = end($serverIds);
       $imgUrl= $this->hh($media_id);
       array_push($this->imgArray,$imgUrl);
       //remove last element
       array_pop($serverIds);
       $this->test($serverIds);
   }
  return;
 }

  public function hh($m){
    return 'qt'.$m;
  }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo '<pre>';
$obj->main();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use recursion? You are using a complicated solution for a simple problem.

```
public function main()
{
    $serverIds = array('ff23sdf','ggccc');
    $res = array();

    //These three lines replace an entire recursive function, making the code easier and saving a chunk of memory once you start using real arrays
    foreach ($serverIds as $media_id){
        array_unshift($res, $this->hh($media_id));
    }
    var_dump($res);
}

public function hh($m)
{
    return 'qt'.$m;
}
```

Comment: These code is simple demo , I don't think foreach can get what I want, because the real scenario is I need to download some images from other platform, what if the internet is crowded, the result isn't returned,however the foreach is still running.

Comment: when I uploaded some images to third party platform using forEach of javascript , the forEach is running complete, however the result is undefined,